# appium having issue finding a very long accessibility id element

Tags: java, testing, appium

I am testing a mobile application, and haven't had any issues mapping out and identifying all of the accessibility id's so far within the application but I am stuck on not being able to identify one case in particular...

I have a case where one of the accessibility id is very long in the form of "The password must have between 8 and 16 characters. It must contain at least 1 number, 1 letter, and 1 non-alphanumeric characters". When I specify this accessibility in my code, I keep getting consistent errors that the element can't be found. Is there a workaround for this, to maybe shorten this or any other solution?

I've tried searching around for this solution, but haven't been able to find anything and have been stuck on this the past day. Please help :)

```java
String actual_error= driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("The password must have between 8 and 16 characters. It must contain at least 1 number, 1 letter, and 1 non-alphanumeric character").getText();
String expected_error= "The password must have between 8 and 16 characters. It must contain at least 1 number, 1 letter, and 1 non-alphanumeric character";
Assert.assertEquals(actual_error, expected_error);
```

Comment: A few things you could try to identity the problem: 1. Isolate problem by putting relevant code in a separate script. 2. If you have access to the source code, try the following: a. replace the AutomationID with numbers or letters, same length. This is to check if the original ID has certain problematic characters. b. Is the problem persists, shorten the ID, it could be to long. c. Put the ID on another element and see if the problem moves with it. d. isolate problem in the app. 3. If you don't have access to source code, contact the devs.